# Insert dynamic JSON data into Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization

I want to insert JSON data into sql server table i retrive my json data through URL  and i have written my insert logic on button click event its through obvious error `{"Must declare the scalar variable \"@Name\"."}` because i dint supply any parameters for inserting data because i can not pass those parameters hard coded they

```
private string HttpContent(string url)
        {
            WebRequest objRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            return result;
        }
        protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLDBConnection"];
            string strConnString = conString.ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            SqlCommand com;
            string data = HttpContent(txturl.Text);
                JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var table = jsSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(data);
                conn.Open();
                com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_insert_json (Name, Mobile, Email) VALUES(@Name, @Mobile, @Email)", conn);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                int refId = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                if (refId > 0)
                {
                    Response.Write("{\"response\":{\"status\":\"success\",\"msg\":\"Details Saved Successfully..\"}}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("{\"response\":{\"status\":\"fail\",\"msg\":\"oops!! something went wrong\"}}");
                }
            }
```

Now My question is what should i change or how can insert my data into sql server table

i use for each loop for mapping each row and then insert but not worked for me Please share any idea or method to insert data into table?? i am getting problem in this section `com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_insert_json (Name, Mobile, Email) VALUES(@Name, @Mobile, @Email)", conn);` how to insert these parameters into table

Comment: in the shared code you are not replacing the parameters "@Name", "@Mobile", "@Email"

Comment: @AhmedMsaouri yes i know as i mention i din't pass add with value for name mobile and email because i am not inserting these value on my page directly i want to insert into database is it possible to read my json data and insert into database??

Answer (score 0):

have to add the parameters to replace the parameters with the json values,after the instance line of the SqlCommand object, like :

```
    com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_insert_json (Name, Mobile, Email) VALUES(@Name, @Mobile, @Email)", conn);
    com.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NChar);
    com.Parameters["@Name"].Value = "NameDataJson";

    com.Parameters.Add("@Mobile", SqlDbType.NChar);
    com.Parameters["@Mobile"].Value = "MobileDataJson";

    com.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NChar);
    com.Parameters["@Email"].Value = "EmailDataJson";
```

Comment: sqlDbType does not contain definition of string

Comment: have to import the library using System.Data; 
or use System.Data.SqlDbType.String

Comment: have to import the library System.Data.SqlClient.dll and System.Data.dll

Comment: System.Data.dll has installed but System.Data.SqlClient.dll  is not there and even i search in Assemblies but dint find

Comment: but if you use SqlConnection you have to import System.Data.SqlClient !!!!

Comment: you can find in Framework \ .NET Framework \ v4.x.x \ System.Data.dll

Comment: yes i am using using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

Comment: Sorry is NChar not string